# Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print

Tags: python, printing, multiprocessing

I have a problem with the code below, and with any code that uses the `print` function in the child processes. I can't see any printed statements, even if I use `sys.std[err|out].write('worker')` instead of `print`.

This is the code ([from the official python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

**The output is blank.**

**Note**: The following code uses the threading module and it prints the output:

```
import threading

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = threading.Thread(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

**Output**: `hello bob`

Can you please point me to the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python 2.7.15 (Mac) both programs output `hello bob`. This is likely platform specific.

Comment: Can you try adding the -u parameter to your python interpreter when you run it? It should unbuffer your output. (something like python -u myscript.py)

Comment: As far as I can tell, running this script in a terminal (and importantly outside an IDE) works. Python tested=3.9.5. I modified the `print` statement to `print()` command in Python3.

Answer (score 48):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name
    sys.stdout.flush()

...
```

AFAIK the standard output of processed spawned by the `multiprocessing` module is buffered, hence you will see the output only if the buffer becomes full or you explicitly flush `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Which platform are you on? The above works for me on Mac OS X; in fact, it works even without flushing sys.stdout.

Comment: Tamas, the platform I'm working on is win32.

By the way, until now I tried to run the code within IDLE. Today I tried to run it from the command line, using this syntax:
    python.exe my_prog.py
and it worked.

Anybody knows why? And how can I display print output by running programs within IDLE?

Comment: Well, IDLE is a strange thing. In order to "capture" everything what you write using `print` statements or `sys.stdout.write`, IDLE "overrides" `sys.stdout` and replaces it with an object that passes everything back to IDLE so it can print it. I guess when you are starting a new process from `multiprocessing`, this hackery is not inherited by the child process, therefore you don't see anything in IDLE. But I'm just guessing here, I don't have a Windows machine at the moment to check it.

Comment: Got it for windows?

Comment: It works on Windows, but you see the printed message in the main CMD process. In my case, it was the CMD window, where I started jupyter.

Comment: In Python 3, there is a parameter for flushing `print('hello', name, flush=True)`

Answer (score 9):

The docs for multiprocessing clearly explain [why](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) this won't work!

"Note: Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ method be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter."

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.

What I did is to write the code in a file named "example.py" and to hit F5 to run it. Maybe this means "running code within IDLE"?

PS: I am a python newbie, so sorry for any (excessively) obvious thing I may have stated here.

Comment: Ah, well yes IDLE with the ">>" prompt counts as an interactive interpreter.  So multiprocessing basically won't work unless you write the code in a file and hit F5 as you say or type "python example.py" in the command prompt.  I can understand how this might be a confusing issue.  You're welcome.

Comment: @manifest can you tell me what to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892469/multiprocessing-for-webscrapping-wont-start-on-windows-and-mac

Answer (score 5):

Having run into this issue myself, sometimes this can be because the child process is actually silently failing before ever getting to the print statement. If this is the case, wrapping the child process code in a try-except block and returning the exception object (to be printed in the parent process) is an effective way to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

I was using PyCharm IDE, and by checking the "Emulate terminal in output console" field in Run/Debug Configurations, it printed the desired result.

[image]

Hope it helps if you're using PyCharm.

Comment: `p.run()` is an internal function meaningful when subclassing `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process`. Is not meant to be called directly. By calling `p.run()` directly, you simply run the function given to the class constructor. The function itself is not run within a thread/process but directly in the main program.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I should delete my answer to prevent misguidance.

Comment: I'd recommend so yes,

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me. (Pycharm)