# multiprocessing.process subclass does not work

Tags: python, inheritance, multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing, and am trying to use the multiprocessing.Process class instead of the threading.Thread class for a project since they apparently have the same variables, however even though I copied [this](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html) code, the run() does not seem to work... could this have to do with the python version or missing files?

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run(self):
        print 'In %s' % self.name
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = Worker()
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

I have found other examples but still don't understand this, please help.

Comment: Works for me (python 2.7.3, ubuntu64). Run from command line as 'python 001.py'. How do you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the differences between the multiprocessing and threading modules. This question is basically identical to [Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You need to call `Process.__init__` from your Worker class. You do not have an `__init__` function in your derived class at present. Nothing will work properly until you do this.
2. The preferred way to communicate the code to be executed is NOT to override `run()` directly, but to use the `target=` argument to `Process`. This allows `Process` to pass arguments to your code in the new process. See the documentation for `multiprocessing.Process` for all the gory details.