# Serial code working well, but not when paralelized

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cython

I created a very extensive Cython code (1300+ lines) to do an specific network operation, and got it working just fine.  It basically receives a bunch of numpy arrays and a couple of SciPy sparse arrays and exports the results as dbf files.
   As I have to run the code for multiple points of origin and destination on the networt, it would be logical to parallelize the code (i'm using a dual xeon 6 core per CPU), but that part is not working.

Below there is the most relevant part of the code.  I'm basically calling the function "run_one_to_all" over and over again for different origins on the network, but when I comment out the serially running line and use the multiprocessing one, I see on my Task manager that the python processes are opened and closed but not even load much memory (each process uses about 400Mb).
   I'm on a windows professional 64 bits, Python 2.7.3 32Bits, Numpy, SciPy, Cython and other python libraries all in 32bits.

I appreciate any guidance!!!

```
def main():
    ...
    ...
    results=[]
    def adder(value): #Function to hold all the values we will receive for the other cores
        #resultados.append(value)
        results.append(value)


    #Open a pool to perform assignment
    cores=mp.cpu_count()
    pool=mp.Pool(cores)
    for o in range(zones):
        if np.sum(CSFFM_matrix[o,:])>0:  #If we have something coming from that zone
            #q=run_one_to_all(CSFFM_graph,o, CSFFM_matrix[o,:]) #SERIALLY RUNNING
            pool.apply_async(run_one_to_all, args=(CSFFM_graph,o,CSFFM_matrix[o,:]), callback=adder) #PARALLELIZED RUNNING

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def run_one_to_all(CSFFM_graph,o, CSFFM_matrix):

    """#&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

    #here we should remove ALL the centroids connectors leaving ALL other
    #centroids (not origin) from the graph

    #&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"""

    #Load the parameters from the config file
    number_paths=config.number_paths
    zones=config.zones+1
    outfolder=config.output_path

    #Define the numbr of nodes on the graph
    nodes=int(np.max(CSFFM_graph[:,1])+1)
    nodes2=int(np.max(CSFFM_graph[:,2])+1)
    if nodes2>nodes: nodes=int(nodes2)
    Flows=np.zeros(nodes, dtype='float32')

    idsgraph=CSFFM_graph[:,0].astype(int)

    idsgraph=csr_matrix((idsgraph,(CSFFM_graph[:,1],CSFFM_graph[:,2])), shape=(nodes,nodes))

    for d in range(zones):
        if CSFFM_matrix[d]>0 and o<>d:  #If we have something coming from that zone
            name=str(o)+'-'+str(d)
            output=open(config.output_path+name+'.log', 'w')
            t=clock()
            #Start with a new graph cost set
            CSFFM_graph[:,8]=CSFFM_graph[:,7]

            #Generates DAG
            dag=GENERATES_DAG(CSFFM_graph,o,d,number_paths,nodes)

            dag2=coo_matrix(dag)
            sz=dag2.data.shape[0]
            dg=np.empty((sz,2))
            dg[:,0]=dag2.row
            dg[:,1]=dag2.col
            dag2=None

            path_file=NestNetwork(dag, o, d, number_paths)
            print >>output, str(round(clock()-t,3))+ ' s'

            tcw(dg, path_file, nodes, name)
    return Flows
```

It seems to be a Cython problem, as I get the following error when I run it in parallel:
[image: Error when running in parallel:]

Comment: How big are the arguments you're passing? Each one has to be pickled, passed over a pipe, and unpickled, and if they're too big, things can go wrong which aren't always diagnosed nicely.

Comment: I have about 100Mb of data being passed. Don't think that is too much...

Comment: Well, 400Mb seems about right for unpickling 100Mb worth of data plus initial overhead and overallocation, so the multiprocessing is probably working. The question is what each child process is doing. The easiest way to debug that is to put some print or log calls into `run_one_to_all` to make sure it's getting run, see its parameters, etc.

Comment: I added a few calls (creating empty text files), but they did not do anything... It is really like they never started (I would believe that if I had not seen them on the task manager)...

Comment: One more possibility: Do you have any top-level code in the module that's not wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__'`? If that's not the problem, another thing to check is to explicitly pickle and unpickle everything in-process and see if it works, something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ukERmxLd).

Comment: As a side note, it looks like it would be really easy to rework this into a loop around `for o, row in enumerate(CSFFM_matrix)`, and from there to a simple `map`/`pool.map` call (or the `i` and/or `async` equivalents). Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/aR186HEP).

Comment: So I changed the code and I'm only passing "o", which is an integer, and I'm loading the np arrays from disc just for testing, and the result is the same. I imagined that it could be a matter of faulty Python installation, but other parallel code work fine.  Could it be a problem with the Cython functions I call inside the run_to_all?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a possible problem or not, but it should be pretty easy to test it by writing a stripped-down example in two versions, one of which makes a Cython-function call, one of which doesn't.

Comment: I dug a little deeper and found out that it WAS showing an error, but both IDLE and PyScripter (my IDE of choice) do not show them. This thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/2774623/407861 explains why.  It also seems to be a cython problem (generates_dag and NestNetwork are custom cython functions). I'll dig into that.