# Jupyter notebook shows output in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, module, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using an Jupyter notebook, but when I try to print something to get any output by simply giving the variable name and pressing Shift + Enter, instead of getting the output in notebook (next to the cell), I get it in the terminal from where I launch the notebook. I want to see the output in the notebook itself, and ultimately store the data as a dataframe and export as csv.

The code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import datetime
import time
import worker

start = time.time()

if __name__ ==  '__main__': 
  pool = []
  numdays = 365
  start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15 )  #year - month - day
  datelist = [
        (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for x in 
        range(0, numdays)
        ]

pool = Pool(processes=16)
pool.map(worker.load, datelist)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

and the worker module

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import urllib
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import time
from io import StringIO

symbols = ['AAP']
start = time.time()
dflist = []

def load(date):
    if date is None:
        return
    url = "http://regsho.finra.org/FNYXshvol{}.txt".format(date)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter='|')
        if any(df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)):
            stocks = df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)]
            print(stocks.to_string(index=False, header=False))
            # Save stocks to mysql
        else:
            print(f'No stock found for {date}' )
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        pass
```

[The results in the terminal are as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xH0.png)

I want to be able to simply have this data as a dataframe.
I suspect it's due to the the Jupyter notebook having problems with the module.

Comment: Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806280/3923163) explaining why this is happening and won't work. Do you have to use multiprocessing? If not, then your problem goes away.

Comment: @kdq0 i tried to fix it by using concurrent.futures but I made a mess and doesn't work for me aswell

Comment: Is concurrency a requirement?