# Issue with Python's Multiprocessing in Google Colab

Tags: python, multiprocessing, google-colaboratory

I need to do some multiprocessing with my Python scripts and I decided to give it a try with Google's collaboratory.

I've connected to local runtime and tried to run the following script:

```
import multiprocessing

def spawn(num):
  print('Spawned! {}'.format(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn, args=(i,))
    p.start()
```

However, when I run this, nothing happens. Absolutely nothing, no errors, no prints, it just executes instantly and that's it.

Am I missing something? Does multiprocessing work with Google Colab local runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: do we have multiprocessing within Colab!? That would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this instead

```
import multiprocessing
def spawn(num):
  print('Spawned! {}'.format(num))

for i in range(5):
  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn, args=(i,))
  p.start()
```

Comment: I think this needs a tab in the print('Spawned... bit.  When I do this, it works.

Comment: yeah ofc ,first time using stackoverflow submit

Comment: do we have multiprocessing within Colab!? That would be awesome