# Python Multiprocessing runs entire Program instead of called function

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

print('test')

def plint():
    print('here')

def parallel():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        p1 = Process(target = plint)
        p1.start()

while True:
    parallel()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The program only outputs 'test' all the time, without going to the 'plint' function and printing 'here'. Can anyone help?

Edit: When I run the same code without the loop it outputs 'test' twice and then prints 'here' once. With the loop it doesn't even get to the 'here'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especially on Windows, the main entrypoint of a multiprocessing script [must be guarded by `if __name == "__main__":`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) (see the "safe importing" section).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import os


def plint():
    print("here", os.getpid())


def parallel():
    p1 = Process(target=plint)
    p1.start()


def main():
    print("test")
    while True:
        parallel()
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Now it works! The problem was that it runs everything outside of the main function, and so prints 'test' even when it shouldn't.