# Why is my print statement not reached after parallel processing?

Tags: python, class, time, multiprocessing, scoping

I've written a function that runs a stochastic simulation of a series of chemical reactions, heres a brief summary of the function:

```
def stochastic_simulation(*args): # arguments are a series of arrays
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    update molecule numbers for each species in model
    update current time of the system 
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
return popul_num_all, tao_all, t.get_accumulated_time() # popul_num_all is an array of changing molecule numbers over time, tao_all is the evolution of time throughout the simulation.
```

The `SimulationTimer` is a custom made timer:

```
class TimeError(Exception):
"""A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer Class""" 
pass

class SimulationTimer:  
    def __init__(self):
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        self._simulation_stop_time = None 
        self.accumulated_elapsed_time = 0.0

    def start(self):
        """start a new timer"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")

        self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()  
    def stop(self):
        """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is None:
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

        self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - 
        self._simulation_start_time  
        self.accumulated_elapsed_time += elapsed_simulation_time

        self._simulation_start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_simulation_time:0.10f} seconds")

    def get_accumulated_time(self):
        """ Return the elapsed time for later use"""
        return self.accumulated_elapsed_time
```

I'm trying to run `stochastic_simulation` in parallel using the `pool` method of the `multiprocessing` library. `t.get_accumulated_time()` is meant to be the time it takes to run all my simulations in parallel.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(stochastic_simulation, [start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array])

        total_time = 0.0
        for tuple_results in pool_results:
            total_time += tuple_results[2] 
    print(f"Total time:\n{total_time}")
```

The above code is how I run the parallel simulations, and there are two issues with it. Firstly, It never actually reaches the print statement, `f"Total time:\n{total_time}"` is never printed. Secondly, it never returns one combined measure of time taken to run all parallel simulations `t.get_accumulated_time()` instead it returns a separate time for each of the processes.

I'm not sure if these issues are to do with `scoping` the `class object` or the `multiprocessing`.

EDIT:

My inputs into the `stochastic_simulation`are all arrays.
That describe the following system:

```
1S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 0U
2S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 1T + 0U 
0S + 1T + 0U --> 2S + 0T + 0U
0S + 1T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 1U
```

1. `initial_state` this is the number of each molecule species at time zero. in my model there are 4 species so it has len = 3
2. `LHS` is a 2D array of ratios between the reactants of different reactions.
3. `stoch_rate` is the rate of each reaction an array of length 4
4. `state_change_array` is the net change in molecules after a reaction fires.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the code to fix the indentation.  We can't tell what items are supposed to be members of the `SimulationTimer` class, nor what code is supposed to be indented underneath the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print

Comment: In my experience you cant print() to stdout from a child process in the console where you have the parent process. You could add an process identifier to the string that you want to print, save the string in a variable and return it to the parent process and print it there instead. Also, you class variable accumulated_elapsed_time ought to be an instance variable instead defined under __init__.

Comment: by example of in parallel do you mean 4 parallel simulations with 1 argument each? or do you mean an example of 1 (or more) parallel simulations with 4 arguments each? - wondering if there is unintended behaviour in p.map, just trying to better understand

Comment: Edited the indentation. I'm trying to run the whole 'stochastic_simulation' function with all the required arguments (so 4 arguments) 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a minimal reproducible example using the below code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def stochastic_simulation(*args): # arguments are a series of arrays
    print('args are:', *args)
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    # update molecule numbers for each species in model
    # update current time of the system 
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
    return t.get_accumulated_time() # deleted some returns

class TimeError(Exception):
    """A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer Class""" 
    pass

class SimulationTimer: 
    accumulated_elapsed_time = 0.0  

    def __init__(self):
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        self._simulation_stop_time = None 

    def start(self):
        """start a new timer"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")

        self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()  
        
    def stop(self):
        """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is None:
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

        self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - self._simulation_start_time  
        self.accumulated_elapsed_time += elapsed_simulation_time

        self._simulation_start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_simulation_time:0.10f} seconds")

    def get_accumulated_time(self):
        """ Return the elapsed time for later use"""
        return self.accumulated_elapsed_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(stochastic_simulation, [1,2,3,4]) #changed inputs
        print(pool_results)
        total_time = 0.0
        for tuple_results in pool_results:
            total_time += tuple_results #removed the [2] index
    print(f"Total time:\n{total_time}")
```

output:

```
args are: 1
Elapsed time: 0.0000015800 seconds
Accumulated time: 0.0000015800 seconds
args are: 2
Elapsed time: 0.0000011850 seconds
Accumulated time: 0.0000011850 seconds
args are: 3
Elapsed time: 0.0000007900 seconds
Accumulated time: 0.0000007900 seconds
args are: 4
Elapsed time: 0.0000007900 seconds
Accumulated time: 0.0000007900 seconds
[1.580000000001025e-06, 1.184999999986891e-06, 7.900000000005125e-07, 7.900000000005125e-07]
Total time:
4.344999999988941e-06
```

This leads me to believe something funky is going on with your inputs perhaps..not sure what calculations you are trying to do between the timers, but would try to narrow down exactly where the code is stopping

Also, if you want to run 4 simulations with 4 arguments each, you should provide a list of lists of arguments, i.e. `[[1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1], [23,23,63,2], [6,2,1,5]]`

Comment: please share what you inputs actually look like to get a better understanding of what you're ttrying to do with them, I have a feeling this might actually be a starmap problem but it just wasn't articulated that way

Comment: See the edit for what the inputs are is that what you meant? The other thing is I need to returns that you deleted because they are passed to another function and used to plot a graph of molecule numbers over time

Comment: I don't have your inputs and you don't have any code that generates those returns in your OP, so I commented them out and was able to run it with minor modifications, which leads me to believe the problem is the functions that generate those two returns, or the inputs themselves

Comment: Sorry for the late comment! I've done a bit more research about printing child processes etc, and just wanted to ask what operating system you used to get the above code working? Did you use forking etc? I'm currently on Windows and wondered if that was part of my problem.

Comment: I used windows10 for this, and not sure what forking means but I'm gonna say no