# python3 multiprocessing map_async not running all tasks

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, slurm

My code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def myfunc(args):
    val1, val2 = args
    print("now running", val1, val2, "node=", mp.current_process().name)
    do_stuff()
    return (args, output)

args = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), ...] # 27654 args

pool = mp.Pool(processes = 16)

gen_output = pool.map_async(myfunc, args)

for output in gen_output.get(): 
    args_copy, output_i = output
```

My initial list (args) has 27,654 tuples, but after counting the printout ("now running"), I only get 14,671 back. Also, I can't easily check, but it also seems I dont get output for the args that don't print out. 
There is no error message or warning other than the printout of the args that did run. \

I suspect some child nodes didn't run at all. Does anyone know what may cause this and how to get around? 
The printing statement should tell me which task is running on each child node. But oftern times it only prints 6 or 7 different children "ForkPoolWorker" 1,5,6,9,12,16 for example. \
I am using a SLURM cluster to run this script and request 16 nodes.

```
>>> cat job.sh
/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o tmp.out
#SBATCH -e tmp.err
#SBATCH -n 16 
#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --mem=16g

python3 my_script.py. -n 16
```

argument `n` will go to `pool = mp.Pool(processes = options.n)`

Comment: "I am using a SLURM cluster to run this script and request 16 nodes." Does each node run the same script? Does each node run part of the script?

Comment: As far as I understand, each node runs myfunc with a subset of the args

Comment: How did you submit the script? Can you provide a Slurm jobscript?

Comment: Is SLURM actually relevant here? Do you observe the same behavior when running it on a single node via SLURM or when running it locally?

Comment: I noticed that the SLURM was pretty busy and only 8 CPUs were available. When I request pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4) it runs fine

Comment: Just FYI: pythons multiprocessing does not work across nodes. If you really request 16 nodes, you might waste a lot of ressources, depending on how you submit this to Slurm.

Comment: @MarcusBoden Please check the edits I made. I am not really sure how to check if I am actually using all nodes, but it does run fasta when I request SBATC n=16 compared SBATCH n=1 and when I print m.current_process().name, I get  "ForkPoolWorker-1","ForkPoolWorker-2"....

Comment: ist it really `/usr/bin/python` in the first line? It should be `#!bin/bash` or something similar.

Comment: sorry yeah, fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna answer my own question. I found this other issue [Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print) which seems to be identical to my own. 
I just added the `sys.stdout.flush()` and `sys.stderr.flush()` after my printing statements and I get the right count. 
Also, the missing output was another unrelated bug. I double checked and even when the pintout does not match the expected count, the function still returns the right number of output.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` as more generic approach?

```py
import concurrent.futures

def myfunc(args):
    val1, val2 = args
    print("now running", val1, val2)
    do_stuff()
    return (args, output)

args = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), ...] # 27654 args
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    for args_copy, output in executor.map(myfunc, args):
        ...
```

> I am using a SLURM cluster to run this script and request 16 nodes.

Your code apparently knows nothing about the SLURM and starts 16 processes *per node*. Is this what you're trying to do?