# Child process doesn't print from Multi processing.process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Language: Python

Operation: Multi-Processing

I ran into an issue where my pooled function refuses to print in
either VS Studio Code, Pycharm and console,

I also tried these out but no luck
[Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print)

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

```
#Example.py
import sys
import os

def check_n(x):

    print ("The arguments are: " , str(sys.argv))
    print("Access Granted")

    print(f"Check_n is being read: ", x)
    sys.stdout.write('gfg')

    #sys.stdout.flush()
    return 0
```

```
#Main.py
import multiprocessing
import Example

if __name__ == '__main__':
process_list = []
for x in df_Pos:   
    print(x)
    p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=Example.check_n, args = (x))
    p.start()   
    p.run()
    
process_list.append(p)
for process in process_list:
    process.join()
```

Yes I have tried to call the module within the same file as the multiprocessing.process but the child process refuses to print

Comment: `Example` is a module in your code; it is utterly inappropriate as the `target=` value of a `Process`.  You need to pass a function - which could very well be imported from the module.

Comment: As per the documentation `multiprocessing.Process()` expects `target` to be "the callable object to be invoked by the run() method" - a module is not a callable object. The module is executed when first imported. If you want `run()` to call anything, you need to pass something callable with `target`, like a function as @jasonharper suggested. When you need to ask a question, you've probably run into a bit of a roadblock, so it's wise to assume you're probably wrong about something - don't dismiss people's suggestions out of hand when they point something out conflicting with what you believed.

Comment: That was not my intention Grismar and thank you for your observation jasonharper you were right the answer was  p.run()

Comment: Is your question answered then? I see you edited the question to include this change already so perhaps it still doesn't run, and you have another problem? At the moment All I see is incorrect indentation (I assume as the result of copy-paste in the stack overflow editor). I would also add a comma in the `Process` constructor: `args=(x,)` to make sure `args` is interpreted as a tuple rather than mathematical parenthesis.

Comment: Yes this question was answered in full, thank you