# multiprocessing library problem in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a problem with a multiprocessing library in Python.
The library is installed, I'm sure about this.

```
def foo():
    print("hello")

import multiprocessing as mp

task = mp.Process(target = foo)
task.start()
```

I expect the program to print `hello` but it does not output anything.

I uninstalled this library with pip and installed again but the resulte didn't change.

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow about not-working `print` in the process. E.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print). Have you checked that question and its answers?

Comment: try running your code in a terminal without IDE. It may be your IDE redirects stdout of the main process in order to render text output in its own window, but child processes are not redirected and are therefore not displayed.

Comment: multiprocessing is not a third-party library, but part of the standard library. you shouldn't be able to use pip to uninstall and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot about to use `task.join()` . Without join(), the main program might terminate before the child process has a chance to complete its execution.

Comment: hello. thank you for your helping. I add join to my program but resulte is nothing also. I added this to end of the program: "sleep(1) ; task.join();"

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

1. Others have mention that you forgot to call `join(), with explanation
2. You need to guard your code inside an `if __name__` block, or you will get an error. I have a feeling that you saw that error already. It looks like this:

```
...
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

That being said, here is a revised version of your code:

```py
import multiprocessing


def foo():
    print("hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    task = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    task.start()
    task.join()
```

Comment: I ran your code in my python idle, but resulte is nothing also. I expected resulte be "hello" in exit. I also do not see any errors

Comment: Have you tried running your script from command line such as `python3 script.py`?

Comment: yes. it worked this way. but why it's not working from python idle?

Comment: @farshadarbab What IDE are you using? some do not handle output from child processes correctly.